# Python equivalent to AudioKit in Swift?

Tags: python, midi, coremidi, midi-interface

I am trying to find a way to visualize MIDI, in which the user much like a DAW, can see the MIDI events and edit them with a Mouse. I know in Swift, people have used Audio Kit but I am not sure if there is an equivalent for Python.

I have tried to used SimpleCoreMidi, but it seems as though that is only used to get python recognized as a MIDI device.